# "error: closure may outlive the current function" but it will not outlive it

Tags: closures, rust, lifetime

When I try to compile the following code:

```
fn main() {

    (...)

    let mut should_end = false;

    let mut input = Input::new(ctx);

    input.add_handler(Box::new(|evt| {
        match evt {
            &Event::Quit{..} => {
                should_end = true;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }));

    while !should_end {
        input.handle();
    }
}

pub struct Input {
    handlers: Vec<Box<FnMut(i32)>>,
}

impl Input {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Input {handlers: Vec::new()}
    }
    pub fn handle(&mut self) {
        for a in vec![21,0,3,12,1] {
            for handler in &mut self.handlers {
                handler(a);
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn add_handler(&mut self, handler: Box<FnMut(i32)>) {
        self.handlers.push(handler);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `should_end`, which is owned by the current function
```

I can't simply add `move` to the closure, because I need to use `should_end` later in the main loop. I mean, I can, but since `bool` is `Copy`, it will only affect the `should_end` inside the closure, and thus the program loops forever.

As far as I understand, since `input` is created in the main function, and the closure is stored in `input`, it couldn't possibly outlive the current function. Is there a way to express to Rust that the closure won't outlive `main`? Or is there a possibility that I can't see that the closure will outlive `main`? In the latter case, it there a way to force it to live only as long as `main`?

Do I need to refactor the way I'm handling input, or is there some way I can make this work. If I need to refactor, where can I look to see a good example of this in Rust?

Here's [a playpen of a simplified version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=828b8a7c4f9898325235&version=stable). It is possible I made a mistake in it that could crash your browser. I happened to me once, so, beware.

In case it is needed, the rest of [my code is available](https://github.com/42f87d89/hook/tree/e4ed1fc90e11c2310fdfaae8285bcda840a917f2). All the relevant info should be in either `main.rs` or `input.rs`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is not your closure, but the `add_handler` method. Fully expanded it would look like this:

```
fn add_handler<'a>(&'a mut self, handler: Box<FnMut(i32) + 'static>)
```

As you can see, there's an implicit `'static` bound on the trait object. Obviously we don't want that, so we introduce a second lifetime `'b`:

```
fn add_handler<'a, 'b: 'a>(&'a mut self, handler: Box<FnMut(i32) + 'b>)
```

Since you are adding the `handler` object to the `Input::handlers` field, that field cannot outlive the scope of the `handler` object. Thus we also need to limit its lifetime:

```
pub struct Input<'a> {
    handlers: Vec<Box<FnMut(i32) + 'a>>,
}
```

This again requires the impl to have a lifetime, which we can use in the `add_handler` method.

```
impl<'a> Input<'a> {
    ...
    pub fn add_handler(&mut self, handler: Box<FnMut(i32) + 'a>) {
        self.handlers.push(handler);
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is using a `Cell` to control access to your `should_end` flag.

Comment: I just need to read up on `Cell` and such. Otherwise, very thorough answer, thank you.

Comment: Where does that implicit `'static` come from, is that documented somewhere?

Comment: iirc if you don't specify a lifetime it's always `'static` except in function arguments and local bindings, which can obviously infer shorter lifetimes

Comment: There's an RFC somewhat related to the topic: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1214-projections-lifetimes-and-wf.md

Comment: Why have you written `'b: 'a` ? Why not just `'b`? What is the rationale behind that constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an example of the fixed code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e7de04e15ca64299f01f&version=stable):

```
use std::cell::Cell;

fn main() {
    let should_end = Cell::new(false);
    let mut input = Input::new();
    input.add_handler(Box::new(|a| {
        match a {
            1 => {
                should_end.set(true);
            }
            _ => {
                println!("{} {}", a, should_end.get())
            }
        }
    }));
    let mut fail_safe = 0;
    while !should_end.get() {
        if fail_safe > 20 {break;}
        input.handle();
        fail_safe += 1;
    }
}

pub struct Input<'a> {
    handlers: Vec<Box<FnMut(i32) + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Input<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Input {handlers: Vec::new()}
    }
    pub fn handle(&mut self) {
        for a in vec![21,0,3,12,1,2] {// it will print the 2, but it won't loop again
            for handler in &mut self.handlers {
                handler(a);
            }
        }
    }
    pub fn add_handler(&mut self, handler: Box<FnMut(i32) + 'a>) {
        self.handlers.push(handler);
    }
}
```