# return a closure that mutates its environment

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I'm writing a simple program that walks a directory, reading its entries and producing a JSON structure. I ran into trouble when I tried to return a closure that mutates a captured `&mut Vec` parameter:

```
use std::io;
use std::fs::{self, DirEntry,};
use std::path::Path;

extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json;


// json encoding: 
#[derive(Debug, RustcEncodable)]
struct Doc {
    path: String,
    filename: String,
}


fn main() {
    let target_path = Path::new("/Users/interaction/workspace/temp/testeddocs");
    let mut docs: Vec<Doc> = Vec::new();

    fn create_handler(docs: &mut Vec<Doc>) -> &FnMut(&DirEntry) {
        let handler = |entry: &DirEntry| -> () {
            let doc = Doc {
                path: entry.path().to_str().unwrap().to_string(),
                filename: entry.file_name().into_string().unwrap(),
            };
            docs.push(doc);
        };

        &handler
    }
    {
        let handler = create_handler(&mut docs);
        visit_dirs(&target_path, & |entry: &DirEntry|{
            handler(entry);
        });
    }
    println!("result json is: {}", json::encode(&docs).unwrap());
}

// one possible implementation of walking a directory only visiting files
fn visit_dirs(dir: &Path, cb: &Fn(&DirEntry)) -> io::Result<()> {
    if try!(fs::metadata(dir)).is_dir() {
        for entry in try!(fs::read_dir(dir)) {
            let entry = try!(entry);
            if try!(fs::metadata(entry.path())).is_dir() {
                try!(visit_dirs(&entry.path(), cb));
            } else {
                cb(&entry);
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

here's the compiler error it gives:

```
error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `***handler` as mutable
--> src/main.rs:36:13
   |
36 |             handler(entry);
   |             ^^^^^^^

error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `docs`, which is owned by the current function
--> src/main.rs:23:23
   |
23 |         let handler = |entry: &DirEntry| -> () {
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `docs`
...
28 |             docs.push(doc);
   |             ---- `docs` is borrowed here
   |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `docs` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
|         let handler = move |entry: &DirEntry| -> () {

error: `handler` does not live long enough
--> src/main.rs:31:10
   |
31 |         &handler
   |          ^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
32 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 22:64...
--> src/main.rs:22:65
   |
22 |     fn create_handler(docs: &mut Vec<Doc>) -> &FnMut(&DirEntry) {
   |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["error: closure may outlive the current function" but it will not outlive it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651279/error-closure-may-outlive-the-current-function-but-it-will-not-outlive-it)

Comment: it's not a strict duplicate, since you are trying to violate multiple borrowing rules, but it has the same underlying issue that you have once you fix all the nits.

Comment: ok, i'll look into the link you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of fumbling, I think I have found a solution, by leveraging `Box` and `move` (`move + Box` don't create a deep clone).

But it is not good as I wanted, because I have to change `visit_dirs` signature (that piece of code is copied from rust doc, so I don't want change it). If anyone has a better suggestion, please let me know.

to @ker & @aochagavia, thanks for your help, it is truly appreciated.

```
use std::io;
use std::fs::{self, DirEntry,};
use std::path::Path;

extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json;


// json encoding: 
#[derive(Debug, RustcEncodable)]
struct Doc {
    path: String,
    filename: String,
}


fn main() {
    let target_path = Path::new("/Users/interaction/workspace/temp/testeddocs");
    let mut docs: Vec<Doc> = Vec::new();

    fn create_handler<'a>(docs: &'a mut Vec<Doc>) -> Box<FnMut(&DirEntry) + 'a> {
        let handler = move |entry: &DirEntry| -> () {
            let doc = Doc {
                path: entry.path().to_str().unwrap().to_string(),
                filename: entry.file_name().into_string().unwrap(),
            };
            docs.push(doc);
        };

        Box::new(handler)
    }

    {
        let mut handler = create_handler(&mut docs);
        visit_dirs(&target_path, &mut |entry: &DirEntry|{
            handler(entry)
        });
    }
    println!("result json is: {}", json::encode(&docs).unwrap());
}

// one possible implementation of walking a directory only visiting files
fn visit_dirs(dir: &Path, cb: &mut FnMut(&DirEntry)) -> io::Result<()> {
    if try!(fs::metadata(dir)).is_dir() {
        for entry in try!(fs::read_dir(dir)) {
            let entry = try!(entry);
            if try!(fs::metadata(entry.path())).is_dir() {
                try!(visit_dirs(&entry.path(), cb));
            } else {
                cb(&entry);
            }
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

If you look carefully at `create_handler`, you will see that `handler` will be destroyed at the end of the function, since it is just a local variable. Therefore Rust forbids any references to `handle` that may be used from outside the function. Otherwise, the references would point to data that is no longer available (the classical dangling pointer bug).

### Solution 1: boxing the closure

You can return the closure as a trait object by boxing it (allocating on the heap). This is the only way to do it in stable Rust (1.14):

```
fn create_handler(docs: &mut Vec<Doc>) -> Box<FnMut(&DirEntry)> {
    let handler = |entry: &DirEntry| -> () {
        let doc = Doc {
            path: entry.path().to_str().unwrap().to_string(),
            filename: entry.file_name().into_string().unwrap(),
        };
        docs.push(doc);
    };

    Box::new(handler)
}
```

### Solution 2: returning the closure by value

While this does not work in stable Rust (1.14), you can use it on nightly. The benefit of this approach is that it avoids the heap allocation:

```
fn create_handler(docs: &mut Vec<Doc>) -> impl FnMut(&DirEntry) {
    let handler = |entry: &DirEntry| -> () {
        let doc = Doc {
            path: entry.path().to_str().unwrap().to_string(),
            filename: entry.file_name().into_string().unwrap(),
        };
        docs.push(doc);
    };

    handler
}
```

Comment: I tried the first solution before, the problem is the  lifetime of  `&mut Vec<Doc>` cant meets the compiler's requirements. And I dont know how to make this code work. As for solution 2, I'm happy to learn there's another way to return closure, but I'm a rust newbie, and currently I'm only targeting stable version, so it's not applicable for me.